# How to set label text from SQL Server database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

[image]

I need to write label text dynamically without writing it getting database table. How can I get it? So that I need to translate to other language..thanks...

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far?

Comment: ya e.g label.text=obj_dt.string_value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.GetName()` Method in SQLDataReader probably solves your problem by getting the columns names. After that you can set the label text.

for example :

```
var label = new List<Label>(); // store your labels in this list

connection.Open();
command.CommandText = "Your Command";
DataReader = command.ExecuteQuery();
if (DataReader.HasRows) {
    while(DataReader.Read()) {
         for(int i = 0; i < DataReader.FieldCount; i++) {

              // You can get the column names and set the label texts now
              // by making an array or list of labels like :
              label[i].Text = DataReader.GetName(i);                      

         }
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: then how to translate to other language?

Comment: k thanks but how to  translate to other language?

Comment: @Happy: Take a look at the Localization in ASP.Net, this link is a good headstart http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15991/An-Easy-Introduction-to-Localization-in-ASP-NET-2

Comment: @Happy: and also this, http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2010/11/23/multi-lingual-web-applications-using-asp-net-4.aspx